# Stucked in the example of State Monad in Haskell Wiki

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm learning State Monad and cannot understand one example in Wiki (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State)

```
rollDie :: GeneratorState Int
rollDie = do generator <- get
             let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
             put newGenerator
             return value
```

the `put` has definition

```
put newState = State $ \_ -> ((), newState)
```

It seems `put` just create a new `State`, what the real usage of this line? If want to use the value maybe should use `<-` to extract, and if want to use the `state` again should use `get`. It makes no difference if delete this line (or am i missing anything? ), So, what does this line really mean ?

Comment: You can think of `State state a` as a function, that, given a state `state` returns a _new_ state and a value. `put` simply ignores the previous state, returns unit, but sets the given `newState` as state for the next computations.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for reply! I understand what `put` do, but what's the `put newGenerator` usage here ? If I delete this line, does anything change ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete that `put` and get some random values. I predict you will always get the same "random value". That is how the random Generator in haskell works: It (i.e. `randomR`) is a pure function - given the same generator, it will always return the same result. You have to feed the newGenerator to the next call. This is done via `put`.

Comment: That's the reason a good `State` implementation provides `state :: (s -> (a,s)) -> State s b`. Then `rollDie = state (randomR (1,6))`.